# Get "mutual friends" and "mutual likes" using Facebook's Graph Api (v2.8)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get "mutual friends" and "mutual likes" between session-user(i.e. me) and request-user(i.e. some friend of friend) using [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/), but i am receiving an empty list.

The urls I am hitting :
**for mutual friends :**
http://graph.facebook.com/*[request-user-id]*?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)&access_token=*[my-access-token]*

**for mutual likes :**
http://graph.facebook.com/*[request-user-id]*?
fields=context.fields(mutual_likes)&access_token=*[my-access-token]*

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Then you likely don’t have the necessary permissions. And mutual_friends only shows friends that are using the same app.

Comment: Hello @CBroe, 
Can you share your code for getting the mutual_friends?

Comment: What code? The request as you have shown above, works. If you don’t get any results, then likely there are no mutual, app-using friends between the two, or you don’t have `user_friends` permission from both users.